# how to change terminal font size on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the Terminal font size. But I have no idea to do it.

Who can solve it?

[image]

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/change-font-terminal-tool

Answer (score 23):

in window  : File - > Settings - > Editor - > Color scheme -> Console Font

[image]

Answer (score 12):

File > Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) > Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone, I have solve it. I also do this steps some days ago, but it is not effective immediately. I try to do it once again just now and then restart AndroidStudio , Everything is OK. Thanks!

Comment: May you mark any question as a correct so the community can check that answer as a desired one? :)

Answer (score 1):

**In Android Studio 3.0 File > Settings > Editor > Color & Fonts > Console Font....then click Apply and Ok** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are android studio version above 3.0 :

File > Settings > Editor(expand it) > Color scheme(Expand it) > Console Font > Tick checkbox of Use console font instead of **default** > Enter size of font you want use > click Apply > Click Ok